# Trying to detect and populate a form with RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I have an embedded form on a website I own that I'd like to populate and send using RSelenium.

I can't seem to to detect the elements as a first step. Obviously I'd like then to populate and send.

The form code is:

```html
<div id="form">

                            <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" novalidate="">
                            <div class="form-group"><label for="form_Name" class="control-label">Full name<sup>*</sup></label><input required="" pattern="^***+(.****" class="form-control" title="Full name" id="form_Name" type="text" name="form_Name"></div>
                            <div class="form-group"><label for="form_Email" class="control-label">Email address<sup>*</sup></label><input required="" class="form-control" title="Email address" id="form_Email" type="email" name="form_Email"></div>
                            <div class="form-group"><label for="form_Company" class="control-label">Company name<sup>*</sup></label><input class="form-control" title="Company name" required="" id="form_Company" type="text" name="form_Company"></div>
                            <div class="form-group"><label for="custom_Message" class="control-label">Message</label><textarea class="form-control" title="Message" id="custom_Message" name="custom_Message"></textarea></div>
            
            <div><input class="btn-large btn-inverse btn" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

I've tried all the options with:

```
remDr$findElement()
```

but get the same error:

```
Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

The server is definitely up and working - I've successfully taken a screenshot of the site page.

Can anyone help with how to detect the form elements so I can populate all and send please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention what you tried with `findElement()`. Here's a minimal working example that includes your form and code that finds and populates the "Full Name" box. First, I write the HTML code for the form to a temporary file:

```
html <- '<div id="form">
  <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" novalidate="">
    <div class="form-group"><label for="form_Name" class="control-label">Full name<sup>*</sup></label><input required="" pattern="^***+(.****" class="form-control" title="Full name" id="form_Name" type="text" name="form_Name"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="form_Email" class="control-label">Email address<sup>*</sup></label><input required="" class="form-control" title="Email address" id="form_Email" type="email" name="form_Email"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="form_Company" class="control-label">Company name<sup>*</sup></label><input class="form-control" title="Company name" required="" id="form_Company" type="text" name="form_Company"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="custom_Message" class="control-label">Message</label><textarea class="form-control" title="Message" id="custom_Message" name="custom_Message"></textarea></div>           
    <div><input class="btn-large btn-inverse btn" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
  </form>
</div>
'
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
cat(html, file = tmp)
```

Load `RSelenium`, navigate to the page, find the form element, and populate it:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(paste0("file://", tmp))
# Find and populate the field
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "form_Name")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("Foo Bar"))
# Close browser
remDr$close()
```

You can refer to resources like https://ropensci.org/tutorials/rselenium_tutorial/ for more information.

Comment: thanks - did you add the code to a temp file because you didn't have the URL of the page? In which case should the 4th line of the second chunk of code be `remDr$navigate('https://example.com")` ?

Comment: The short answer is yes. I encourage you to refer to the tutorial in the link provided or open a new question if you have follow-ups. It is not good practice at Stack Overflow to answer follow-up questions in the comments section.

Comment: I run into the same problems when using the live page, and I did read the tutorial. `remDr$findElement(using = "id", "form_Name")` gives the same error as above.